# Jqueryui autocomplete, textbox value disappears in IE only when selected

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an issue where I am using Jqueryui autocomplete. The auto-suggest feature works fine, however, when you click to select one of the items in the list the textbox value is deleted and the list disappears, rendering the autocomplete useless.

I cna only assume its conflicting with something else on the page but I am stumped on this and wonder if anyone can help?

This functions correctly in Firefox and Chrome but in IE it does not.

The issue is occurring on this page: http://www.norfolktastesgood.com/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having issues with autocomplete and IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the onClick="this.value='';" attribute on line 83 called cause of bubbling????
try adding an event handler to the input, remove the onclick attribute to test

```
$( "#LocationSearch" ).autocomplete({
    source: SearchList
}).click( function(e){
    if ( $(e.target).is('#LocationSearch'){
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

I'm on a linux machine so can't test this at the minute

Hope it works, let me know